# Styling email links in CSS

Tags: css, selector

I'm just starting off with HTML / CSS and was having a little trouble formatting an email link embedded in a `<p>` tag. What sort of CSS selector could I use to access the `<a>` element here?

I'd like to be able to edit it as a link, hovered over, etc., so a selector using `a:link` or something like it would help. Thanks!

```
<div id="content" class="rounded-corners">
    <h2>Contact Me</h2>
    <p>email: <a href="mailto:foo@bar.com">foo@bar.com</a></p>
    <p>aim: deadunderdecor</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
a[href^="mailto:"] {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Works great, I tried this earlier to no avail and then once again couldn't get this to work after seeing your answer. I then remembered that I had changed the link in my head tag to a different style sheet in order to test something and never switched it back. Doh! Thanks a lot though.

Comment: Where would the :hover go in this case? EDIT: Nevermind, found out from another source that it goes after the right bracket.

Comment: @alex For some reason I can't get the text-decoration:underline; to work. Should a[href^="mailto:"]{text-decoration:underline;} work? I'm using it on other anchors on the page and it works fine.

Comment: @Nick It should, but something may be overwriting it. Inspect it with a tool such as Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS selector?:

```
#content > p > a
```

Comment: This works too, but I chose alex's answer due to the fact that it's more useful in general situations. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Using

#content > p > a

would work but is more performance expensive and less general than merely using

#content a

CSS works by using each select (#content, a, etc.) in the declaration to get to more specific elements. By default, a selector that precedes another selector can have any number of elements in between it and what it precedes. The alternative I suggested would style any link that is inside of an element with an ID of content.

The solution Alex proposed is much more restrictive. Using ">" modifies the selection so that it doesn't match any n-nested element and instead matches only elements that are immediate children of the selector to the left.

I.e. it would work for 
 `

Blah

`

But not for

`

blah

`

Because in the second instance, the P tag is no longer the immediate child of the #content element.

As far as CSS styling goes, you'll want to use the :hover, :visited, and :active pseudo-classes to modify it's appearance while the user is interacting with them.

I.e.

#content a:hover { color: #ff0; } /* changes the color on hover */

There are a lot of good tutorials on the internet that explain this more fully. If you search for CSS anchor pseudo classes, you'll get plenty of good answers.

Comment: I think your code formatting got messed up somewhere, but thank you for the info on selectors. I didn't know what the > meant, so that's helpful.